# Средствами CSS изменить выравнивание, если блок не помещается

Tags: css

В заголовке таблицы есть кнопка сортировки столбца, по нажатию на который появляется меню с вариантами сортировки.

```
<div id="table_col_0" class="fixedColumn">
    <span>Колонка 1<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span>
    <ul class="sort" id="sort_0">
        <li><div>По возрастанию</div></li>
        <li><div>По убыванию</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Стили класса sort. Соответственно, ul прилипнет к правому краю родительского div.

```
right: 0px;
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
```

Если ширина левой колонки будет меньше чем ширина меню сортировки, меню сортировки будет некрасиво выползать, вот так:

[image: Меню сортировки выползает]

Я применяю JS для изменения выравнивания по другому краю и получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть способ сделать это средствами только CSS?

Comment: Вместо `right: 0px;` - `left: 0px;` ? )

Comment: @Moonvvell тогда он не будет по правому краю если ширина колонки будет большая :)

Comment: Ясно что left:0px выровняет по левому краю)) надо, чтобы это было автоматически

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят.

```
.fixedColumn{
  border:1px solid red;
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:right;
}
.sortMenu{
  background:lightblue;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:150px;
}



<div class="fixedColumn">
  <div class="sortMenu">
    xxx
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hcfefm7n/

Ширина блока с классом fixedColumn задает выравнивание